# panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: golang

Пишу проверочною программу для проверки соединения http с сервером, отклика и т.д.  **Это начальный код который реализует множество потоков с нагрузкой на сервер:**

```
package main
import (

    "os"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http" 

)
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1024; i++ {
        go FierceHTTP(os.Args[1], 80)
    }
    var input string 
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}

func FierceHTTP(url string, port int) {


    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    fierce_ua := []string{
        "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; ru) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10",
        "Opera/9.50 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en)",
        "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.5.18 Version/10.50",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; FreeBSD i386; en-US; rv:1.7.8) Gecko/20050609",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.8.1.20) Gecko/20081217 Firefox/2.0.0.20",
        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)",
        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1)",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.10) Gecko/20050716 Firefox/1.0.6",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.7.9) Gecko/20050711 Firefox/1.0.5",
    }
    best_ua := rand.Int() % len(fierce_ua)
    fierce_http, s_err := http.Get(url) 
    fierce_http.Header.Set("User-Agent", fierce_ua[best_ua])
    fierce_http.Header.Set("Referer", "http://128.0.0.1/foo-bar/chinked.html")
    fierce_http.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8")

    if s_err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[Info] [Fatal] HTTP Error... exit")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(fierce_http.Header)
    }

}
```

**Останавливается на рандомном потоке, вот пример ошибки:**

```
goroutine 646 [running]:
main.FierceHTTP(0xc042008320, 0x1b, 0x50)
        C:/codex/src/server.go:36 +0x12a
created by main.main
        C:/codex/src/server.go:13 +0x64
exit status 2
```

Указывает *C:/tamplier/src/server.go:36 +0x12a* мне что что-то неправильное с   **Header.Set** . Программа завершает свое действие посередине, или где-то ближе к началу/концу но не обрабатывается полностью. Как это исправить?

Edit 1 :

```
package main
import (

    "os"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http" 

)
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1024; i++ {
        go FierceHTTP(os.Args[1], 80)
    }
    var input string 
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}

func FierceHTTP(url string, port int) {

    for {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
        fierce_ua := []string{
            "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; ru) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10",
            "Opera/9.50 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en)",
            "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.5.18 Version/10.50",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; FreeBSD i386; en-US; rv:1.7.8) Gecko/20050609",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.8.1.20) Gecko/20081217 Firefox/2.0.0.20",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1)",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.10) Gecko/20050716 Firefox/1.0.6",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.7.9) Gecko/20050711 Firefox/1.0.5",
        }
        best_ua := rand.Int() % len(fierce_ua)
        fierce_http, s_err := http.Get(url) 
        if s_err != nil {
            fmt.Println("[Info] [Fatal] HTTP Error... exit")
            continue

        } else {
            fmt.Println(fierce_http.Header)
        }
        fierce_http.Header.Set("User-Agent", fierce_ua[best_ua])
        fierce_http.Header.Set("Referer", "http://128.0.0.1/foo-bar/chinked.html")
        fierce_http.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8")
    }



}
```

Пытался внести цикл в функцию и при помощи метода continue продолжать выполнение в отдельном потоке, но нечего не выходит.

Comment: Вы не проверяете ошибку `s_err` перед использованием `fierce_http`, который будет `nil`, если есть ошибка.

Comment: @Ainar-G да, пишет что ошибка http как исключение. Я пробовал внести а цикл for в самой функции, и затем продолжать при помощи continue но у меня просто выходит из программы.

Comment: Ну так посмотрите, что за ошибка, и исправьте. Вы же умеете программировать.

Comment: @Ainar-G все я уже решил данную проблему убрав все headers

Answer (score 0):

***Я решил данную проблему убрав все Headers. Код:***

```
package main
import (

    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net/http" 

)
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1024; i++ {
        go FierceHTTP(os.Args[1], 80)
    }
    var input string 
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}

func FierceHTTP(url string, port int) {

    for {

        /* rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
        fierce_ua := []string{
            "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; ru) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10",
            "Opera/9.50 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en)",
            "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.5.18 Version/10.50",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; FreeBSD i386; en-US; rv:1.7.8) Gecko/20050609",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.8.1.20) Gecko/20081217 Firefox/2.0.0.20",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1)",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.10) Gecko/20050716 Firefox/1.0.6",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.7.9) Gecko/20050711 Firefox/1.0.5",
        }
        best_ua := rand.Int() % len(fierce_ua) */

        fierce_http, s_err := http.Get(url) 

        if s_err != nil {
            fmt.Println("[Info] [Fatal] HTTP Error... exit")
            continue

        } else {
            fmt.Println(fierce_http.Header)
        }


    }



}
```